# How to insert php script inside jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, insert

I have this jquery sample, just wondering how to insert php (e.g. /a href="/?php echo $sample['SAMPLE\']; ?/"/) in the "var para1" in the below.

```
            var storyIndictor = jQuery(_storyIndictors[position]);
                var _content = jQuery("div.jqans-content", container);
                var img = jQuery('<img style="float:left;clear:left;"></img>');
                var para = jQuery('<div ></div>');
                var para1 = jQuery('<h1> </h1>');
                var title = jQuery(settings.contentTitle + " a", story).attr('title') || jQuery(settings.contentTitle, story).text();
                img.attr('src', jQuery('img', story).attr('longdesc') || jQuery('img', story).attr('src'));
                para1.html("<h1>" + title + "</h1>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just echo out a variable

```
var para1 = jQuery('<h1><?php echo $another_variable; ?></h1>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _content = jQuery("div.jqans-content", container);
var img = jQuery('<img style="float:left;clear:left;"></img>');
var para = jQuery('<div ></div>');
var para1 = jQuery('<h1><?php echo $phpvar; ?></h1>');
var title = jQuery(settings.contentTitle + " a", story).attr('title') || jQuery(settings.contentTitle, story).text();
img.attr('src', jQuery('img', story).attr('longdesc') || jQuery('img', story).attr('src'));
para1.html("<h1>" + title + "</h1>");
para.html("<p>" + jQuery(settings.contentDescription, story).html() + "</p>");
```

You mean like that?

Comment: Yep.something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var para1 = jQuery('<h1> <?php echo $sample['SaMPLE_SAMPLE']; ?> </h1>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use php inside your js code:-

```
var varName = '<?php echo $sample['SAMPLE']; ?>';
```

don't forget to echo. as you missed in your example

so your var para1 will be:-

```
var para1 = jQuery('<h1><?php echo $sample['SAMPLE']; ?></h1>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to embedded php code in javascript. I have post a way you can try this.

```
<input type="hidden" id="sample" value="<?php echo $sample['SaMPLE_SAMPLE']; ?>" />

or <div id="sample" data-sample="<?php echo $sample['SaMPLE_SAMPLE']; ?>"></div>

<script>
    var sample = $('#sample').val();

    //or
    var sample = $('#sample').data(); //if you use data atrr

    var para1 = $('<h1>' +sample+ '</h1>');
</script>
```

Comment: it will not work. 1) you forget echo variable and 2) and you are using `$` and `jQuery` as well. may be cause of conflict.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your reply.

Comment: Hi, just a clarification, what if the "<?php echo $sample['SaMPLE_SAMPLE']; ?>" is come from "a href"? what would it be like in the jquery?thanks

Comment: If its come from href then its will be GET

Comment: You mean like "var sample = $('#sample').GET();" ? the whole script is like "<a href="<?php echo $sample['SaMPLE_SAMPLE']; ?>">", sorry but im still dumb in using PHP. ;p

Comment: `<input type="hidden" id="sample" value="<?php echo $_GET['SaMPLE_SAMPLE']; ?>" />`

Comment: can we use an href with this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. like 

`var href = $('a').attr('href');`